# MongoDB, mongoose, update object inside array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following MongoDB model:

```
const Relation = mongoose.model('Relation',{
  name :{
    type: String,
  },

  port:{
    type: Number,
  }, 
  services: { type : Array , "default" : [] }
});
```

Each port is a unique number for each document.
A collection could have the following values:

```
{
 "port":"116", //unique number
 "name":"xzy",
 services: [
        {"id":'1', "trust":"good"},
        {"id":'2', "trust":"bad"},
  ]
}
```

How can for example make the "trust" value "bad" for the object with the "id"= 1 ??

I assume I should first find the collection that matchs the port number "116" and then find the object inside the Services array that has the "id" of 1.
How can I do that in mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update value inside an array

```
Relation.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "port": "116", "services.id": "1" },
  { "$set": { "services.$.trust": "bad" }}
)
```